# XSL-FO Paragraph Numbering in Link

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am generating PDFs of S1000D xml and need to display a link to another step, giving that steps number/letter designation. In the below image what currently shows as a link to 1.d. should read 1.c.

[image: Current output]

The source xml containing the ref is as follows:

```
<mainProcedure>
<proceduralStep id="S0001">
    <para id="P0001">REMOVE COMPONENT XYZ.</para>
    <proceduralStep id="S0002">
        <para id="P0002">This is a second level procedural step.</para>
        <proceduralStep id="S0003">
            <para id="P0003">This is a third level procedural step.</para>
            <proceduralStep id="S0004">
                <para id="P0004">This is a fourth level procedural step.</para>
                <proceduralStep id="S0006">
                    <para id="P0006">This is a fifth level procedural step.</para>
                </proceduralStep>
            </proceduralStep>
        </proceduralStep>
    </proceduralStep>
    <proceduralStep id="S0005">
        <para id="P0005">This is a second, second level procedural step.</para>
    </proceduralStep>
    <proceduralStep id="S0008">
        <para id="P0008">The following sub-step has quantity data included.</para>
        <proceduralStep id="S0009">
            <para>Position bracket on frame and secure with bolts and washers. <emphasis
>TORQUE BOLT TO <quantity>
                        <quantityGroup quantityGroupType="minimum"
quantityUnitOfMeasure="ft.lbf">
                            <quantityValue>10</quantityValue>
                        </quantityGroup>
                        <quantityGroup quantityGroupType="maximum"
quantityUnitOfMeasure="ft.lbf">
                            <quantityValue>15</quantityValue>
                        </quantityGroup>
                    </quantity>
                </emphasis>.</para>
        </proceduralStep>
    </proceduralStep>
    <proceduralStep id="S0007">
        <para id="P0007">This is a para with a reference to <internalRef
internalRefId="S0008" internalRefTargetType="step"> another step</internalRef
> in the procedure.</para>
    </proceduralStep>
</proceduralStep>
```

Here is the XSL I have that gives me the incorrect number/letter combo. It appears to be giving me the number for the step that contains the link (there is another template that handles the `<quantity>` data:

```
<xsl:template match="internalRef[@internalRefTargetType='step']">
        <xsl:variable name="refId" select="./@internalRefId"/>
        <xsl:if test="//mainProcedure//proceduralStep/@id = $refId">
            <xsl:if test="//mainProcedure/proceduralStep/@id = $refId">
                <fo:inline>
                    <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{$refId}" color="blue" text-decoration="underline">
                        Step <xsl:number level="multiple" count="mainProcedure/proceduralStep" format="1."/>
                    </fo:basic-link>
                </fo:inline>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="//mainProcedure/proceduralStep/proceduralStep/@id = $refId">
                <fo:inline>
                    <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{$refId}" color="blue" text-decoration="underline">
                        Step <xsl:number level="multiple" count="//mainProcedure/proceduralStep" format="1."/><xsl:number level="single" count="//mainProcedure/proceduralStep | proceduralStep" format="a."/>
                    </fo:basic-link>
                </fo:inline>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Any help getting me on the correct path is much appreciated.

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Comment: Also, if it was a reference to the 3rd level step, would the reference display `1.a.(1)` or `1.a.1.`? What about a 5th level reference?

Comment: @DanielHaley I am using XSLT 2.0, and the order is 1.a.(1)(a)1. The last 1 is underlined.So if i reference a step, it is needed to generate the matching level indicators, with "Step" prior to the numbering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making `xsl:number` too complicated. You should be able to use just one `xsl:number` and eliminate the `xsl:if`'s (by doing an `xsl:apply-templates` and using a moded template).

However, I've run into issues with parens in the `format` attribute, so you might have to do some additional formatting to the resulting number. Also, you'd have to add an `fo:inline` to underline the number for the 5th level step in the reference, but since the entire link is underlined anyway you'd never see it.

Here's an example of what I was thinking. This only handles the references and is for illustration purposes only.

**XML Input** (added additional references at the bottom)

```
<mainProcedure>
    <proceduralStep id="S0001">
        <para id="P0001">REMOVE COMPONENT XYZ.</para>
        <proceduralStep id="S0002">
            <para id="P0002">This is a second level procedural step.</para>
            <proceduralStep id="S0003">
                <para id="P0003">This is a third level procedural step.</para>
                <proceduralStep id="S0004">
                    <para id="P0004">This is a fourth level procedural step.</para>
                    <proceduralStep id="S0006">
                        <para id="P0006">This is a fifth level procedural step.</para>
                    </proceduralStep>
                </proceduralStep>
            </proceduralStep>
        </proceduralStep>
        <proceduralStep id="S0005">
            <para id="P0005">This is a second, second level procedural step.</para>
        </proceduralStep>
        <proceduralStep id="S0008">
            <para id="P0008">The following sub-step has quantity data included.</para>
            <proceduralStep id="S0009">
                <para>Position bracket on frame and secure with bolts and washers. <emphasis
                    >TORQUE BOLT TO <quantity>
                        <quantityGroup quantityGroupType="minimum"
                            quantityUnitOfMeasure="ft.lbf">
                            <quantityValue>10</quantityValue>
                        </quantityGroup>
                        <quantityGroup quantityGroupType="maximum"
                            quantityUnitOfMeasure="ft.lbf">
                            <quantityValue>15</quantityValue>
                        </quantityGroup>
                    </quantity>
                </emphasis>.</para>
            </proceduralStep>
        </proceduralStep>
        <proceduralStep id="S0007">
            <para id="P0007">This is a para with a reference to <internalRef
                internalRefId="S0008" internalRefTargetType="step"> another step</internalRef
                > in the procedure.</para>
            <para>This is a para with a reference to <internalRef
                internalRefId="S0001" internalRefTargetType="step"> another step</internalRef
                > in the procedure.</para>
            <para>This is a para with a reference to <internalRef
                internalRefId="S0002" internalRefTargetType="step"> another step</internalRef
                > in the procedure.</para>
            <para>This is a para with a reference to <internalRef
                internalRefId="S0003" internalRefTargetType="step"> another step</internalRef
                > in the procedure.</para>
            <para>This is a para with a reference to <internalRef
                internalRefId="S0004" internalRefTargetType="step"> another step</internalRef
                > in the procedure.</para>
            <para>This is a para with a reference to <internalRef
                internalRefId="S0005" internalRefTargetType="step"> another step</internalRef
                > in the procedure.</para>
            <para>This is a para with a reference to <internalRef
                internalRefId="S0006" internalRefTargetType="step"> another step</internalRef
                > in the procedure.</para>

        </proceduralStep>
    </proceduralStep>
</mainProcedure>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="internalRef[@internalRefTargetType='step']">
        <xsl:variable name="refId" select="@internalRefId"/>
        <fo:inline>
            <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{$refId}" color="blue" 
                text-decoration="underline">
                <xsl:text>Step </xsl:text> 
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//proceduralStep[@id=$refId]" mode="nbr"/>
            </fo:basic-link>
        </fo:inline>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="proceduralStep" mode="nbr">
        <xsl:variable name="origNbr">
            <xsl:number level="multiple" format="1.a.1.a.1"/>            
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($origNbr,'\.')">
            <xsl:value-of select="if (position()=(3,4)) then concat('(',.,')') 
                else if (position()=5) then . else concat(.,'.')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<mainProcedure>
   <proceduralStep id="S0001">
      <para id="P0001">REMOVE COMPONENT XYZ.</para>
      <proceduralStep id="S0002">
         <para id="P0002">This is a second level procedural step.</para>
         <proceduralStep id="S0003">
            <para id="P0003">This is a third level procedural step.</para>
            <proceduralStep id="S0004">
               <para id="P0004">This is a fourth level procedural step.</para>
               <proceduralStep id="S0006">
                  <para id="P0006">This is a fifth level procedural step.</para>
               </proceduralStep>
            </proceduralStep>
         </proceduralStep>
      </proceduralStep>
      <proceduralStep id="S0005">
         <para id="P0005">This is a second, second level procedural step.</para>
      </proceduralStep>
      <proceduralStep id="S0008">
         <para id="P0008">The following sub-step has quantity data included.</para>
         <proceduralStep id="S0009">
            <para>Position bracket on frame and secure with bolts and washers. <emphasis>TORQUE BOLT TO <quantity>
                     <quantityGroup quantityGroupType="minimum" quantityUnitOfMeasure="ft.lbf">
                        <quantityValue>10</quantityValue>
                     </quantityGroup>
                     <quantityGroup quantityGroupType="maximum" quantityUnitOfMeasure="ft.lbf">
                        <quantityValue>15</quantityValue>
                     </quantityGroup>
                  </quantity>
               </emphasis>.</para>
         </proceduralStep>
      </proceduralStep>
      <proceduralStep id="S0007">
         <para id="P0007">This is a para with a reference to <fo:inline xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
               <fo:basic-link internal-destination="S0008"
                              color="blue"
                              text-decoration="underline">Step 1.c.</fo:basic-link>
            </fo:inline> in the procedure.</para>
         <para>This is a para with a reference to <fo:inline xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
               <fo:basic-link internal-destination="S0001"
                              color="blue"
                              text-decoration="underline">Step 1.</fo:basic-link>
            </fo:inline> in the procedure.</para>
         <para>This is a para with a reference to <fo:inline xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
               <fo:basic-link internal-destination="S0002"
                              color="blue"
                              text-decoration="underline">Step 1.a.</fo:basic-link>
            </fo:inline> in the procedure.</para>
         <para>This is a para with a reference to <fo:inline xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
               <fo:basic-link internal-destination="S0003"
                              color="blue"
                              text-decoration="underline">Step 1.a.(1)</fo:basic-link>
            </fo:inline> in the procedure.</para>
         <para>This is a para with a reference to <fo:inline xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
               <fo:basic-link internal-destination="S0004"
                              color="blue"
                              text-decoration="underline">Step 1.a.(1)(a)</fo:basic-link>
            </fo:inline> in the procedure.</para>
         <para>This is a para with a reference to <fo:inline xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
               <fo:basic-link internal-destination="S0005"
                              color="blue"
                              text-decoration="underline">Step 1.b.</fo:basic-link>
            </fo:inline> in the procedure.</para>
         <para>This is a para with a reference to <fo:inline xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
               <fo:basic-link internal-destination="S0006"
                              color="blue"
                              text-decoration="underline">Step 1.a.(1)(a)1</fo:basic-link>
            </fo:inline> in the procedure.</para>
      </proceduralStep>
   </proceduralStep>
</mainProcedure>
```

Comment: that's twice you've had the answer for me. I was definitely making `<xsl:number>` harder than it needed to be based on this example. Will certainly be revisiting some other XSL in this project that uses numbering.

Comment: @twfurst - Glad I could help. I've worked with S1000D some and lots if iSpec 2200, so if you ever want to talk about anything outside of Stackoverflow, feel free to send me an email.

Comment: thanks for extending the offer, good chance I will hit you up at some point to bounce things off you.